# Convert week and year to milliseconds

Tags: c#

I need to convert, as the title says, weeks and year to milliseconds since 1970. What is the best way to do this in .Net? 
I only have information of the week and year that some event occurred. The week stars on Monday. I think DateTime is not the answer since it can't handle the week of the year.
What I need is something like a method double `getMili(int week, int year)`.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Start by specifying which millisecond in the week you are interested in and also which definition of "week number in year" you follow.

Answer (score 6):

You can put it like that:

```
  // Let's convert 15th Monday in 2014
  int MondaysNumber = 15;

  DateTime source = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);

  int delta = 7 + DayOfWeek.Monday - source.DayOfWeek;

  if (delta >= 7)
    delta -= 7;

  source = source.AddDays((MondaysNumber - 1) * 7 + delta);

  // Finally, convert it into milliseconds 
  Double result = (source - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Good answer. If he uses the ISO week system, for `week == 15` and `year == 2014` as an example, it is better to find the 15th **Thursday** of the year, since Thursday is the middle day of the ISO week and the day that determines what year a week belongs to in cases where January 1 is not a Monday. So find 15th Thursday, then subtract 3 days to get the desired Monday.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Just to check, what week number do we have today, Thursday 6 March 2014? Because today is the 10th Thursday of the year, but the current week started on the 9th Monday of the year. Do you use ISO 8601 weeks?